# Firefox extension - save boolean to storage

Tags: javascript

In the Firefox extension, I want to implement a simple toggle switch that will enable/disable an extension. A basic idea is that the change of state will be saved as a boolean into browser (sync) storage. The state should be read every time, so an extension will know if should work or not.
But - my Javascript knowledge is so poor that I came into trouble.

Here is simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form" class="ps-3 mt-3">
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitch">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitch">Plugin ON/OFF</label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <label id="test"></label>
    <br>
    <script src="options.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is a simple JS file:

```
function CheckAndSave()
{
    var state = document.getElementById("flexSwitch");
    if(state.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'ON';
        browser.storage.sync.set({ delovanje: 1 });
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'OFF';
        browser.storage.sync.set({ delovanje: 0 });
    }
    restoreState();
}

function restoreState()
{
    //browser.storage.sync.get("delovanje", function(items) { console.log(items)});
    let getting4 = browser.storage.sync.get("delovanje");
    getting4.then(setCurrentChoice, onError);

    function onError(error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
      }

    function setCurrentChoice()
    {
      var toggle = document.getElementsByName("flexSwitch");
      if (result.delovanje === 1)
        toggle.checked = true; 
      else
        toggle.checked = false;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreState);
document.getElementById("flexSwitch").addEventListener('change', CheckAndSave);
```

What is wrong with my code? Is my way of saving Boolean ok?
I tried to write to the console for "debugging", but I don't know how to do it - this is a pop-up after a user press an icon, and nothing is shown in the console.

Comment: `var toggle = document.getElementsByName("flexSwitch");` 
Shouldn't this  be  `document.getElementById("flexSwitch");` ?

Answer (score 2):

Most of all you did a mistake here:

```js
  function setCurrentChoice(result)
    {
      var toggle = document.getElementsByName("flexSwitch");
      if (result.delovanje === 1)
        toggle.checked = true; 
      else
        toggle.checked = false;
    }
```

In this case, toggle will be array like object, but not the element you expect.
You should use `document.getElementById("flexSwitch")` as previously.

Another issue that you missed an argument in the `setCurrentChoice` function. It should take settings like this:

```js
 function setCurrentChoice(result){...}
```

I would also suggest to hide the logic of getting element behind the scene by either wrapping it to the function:

```js
const getToggle = () => document.getElementById("flexSwitch")
```

Or even move it to the separate class and encapsulate all logic there:

```js
class Toggle {
  constructor() {
    this._el = document.getElementById("flexSwitch");
  }

  setCheck(value) {
    this._el.checked = value;
  }
}
```

Here is the working sample:

```js
function CheckAndSave()
{
    var state = document.getElementById("flexSwitch");
    if(state.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'ON';
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ delovanje: 1 });
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'OFF';
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ delovanje: 0 });
    }
}

function restoreState()
{
    chrome.storage.sync.get("delovanje",setCurrentChoice );

    function setCurrentChoice(result)
    {
      var toggle = document.getElementById("flexSwitch");
      if (result.delovanje === 1) 
        toggle.checked = true; 
      else
        toggle.checked = false;
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", restoreState);
document.getElementById("flexSwitch").addEventListener('change', CheckAndSave);
```

This approach will help you reduce the code and accidental mistakes.

P.S. [Here is how I worked with the storage](https://github.com/Drag13/HabrSanitizer/blob/master/src/storage.js)

Comment: Thank you. I corrected from "getElementByName" to "getElementByID". But it still doesn't work. It changes the ON/OFF label as it should. But after the window is closed and opened again, there is always OFF position (and not the last/saved as I wish).

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion to make a better code, but as a noob, I'm trying to work with the simplest possible solution.

Comment: @JanezKranjski Found one more issue and updated the answer. Put result as argument into the function setCurrentChoice

Comment: I also changed this. And still doesn't work. I save the video if maybe I'm not clear enough: https://www.kacnje.eu/test/test.html

Comment: It's pretty clear. Could you add `console.log(setting)`  to the `setCurrentChoice`  please?

Comment: "setting"? It isn't there, but I tried it. The console doesn't show anything in this case (please, watch a video). I don't know why ...

Comment: Updated with the working example.  @JanezKranjski

Comment: It works! And it looks almost the same :-) Thank you.

Comment: Good to know. I tried to keep same as much as possible. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The code seems okay, while there are some things I would change (for refactoring purposes to match my flavour) I think it should be working without much issue.

In any case verify the following.

1. The `browser.storage.sync` API is only available from extensions, so check that the HTML and JS that you are posting are actually part of the extension that you are using.
2. The `manifest.json` is what tells the browser what resources can your extension access, verify that you did add the `"storage"` permission on there [here you can read more about it for chrome, though it will be the same for other browsers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#manifest)
3. For debugging purposes always remember that the browser lets you have great tools. Read more about developer tools, but as a starter I would tell you to open them and put a `debugger` statement there where you feel like there's something that isn't working as expected. And then with the console start looking for the properties that you are not finding.
4. To log items to the console use `console.log('XXX')` and it should show what you want

Comment: Tnx. 
1. I know. This code is a part of an extension (for Firefox) code. 2. Manifest has "storage" permission. 3. and 4. - I use logging to console in other parts. But here it simply doesn't work. Now I add writing to the console on four parts of the above code and also add "debugger" statement. It doesn't stop and the console is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the `change` event is not fired when setting `toggle.checked` with JavaScript. Just call `CheckAndSave();` from the end of `setCurrentChoice`.

Comment: Now I use the code from Drag13's answer. It is a little different, but it works :-)